# Array input field names to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How can I break input values from fields named like this:

```
<input name="options[abc][def]">
```

into something like

```
{'options' : { 'abc' : { 'def' : value_of_input } } }
```

I tried

```
$('form').serializeArray()
```

but I get a two dimensional object with keys name liked

options[abc][def]

:|

Comment: Can you tell something more about why you would want this? Thinking out loud I'd suggest using data attributes on your input, but I'm not sure this is of any use in your particular use case.

Comment: Why not store this values directly into the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this library, which does exactly that: [formToObject.js](https://github.com/serbanghita/formToObject.js)

```
<form id="testForm">
    <input name="options[abc][def]" value="test">
    <input type="button" value="Convert to object &raquo;" id="convertBtn">
</form>

<script src="formToObject.js"></script>
<script>
    document.getElementById('convertBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log(new formToObject('testForm'));
        // Output: {"options":{"abc":{"def":"test"}}}
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just this:

HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

Script:

```
var opt = {'options' : { 'abc' : { 'def' : "value" } } };
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="' + opt + '" placeholder="'+ opt + '"/>';
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/JXUd2/)**